# CSS Issue on employee directory alpha search

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, display-template, people-search, directory

I'm using the tutorial linked below to build a SharePoint Online employee directory.
http://sympmarc.com/series/create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-employee-directory-on-office365/
I have everything set up and configured, and it works great... but after clicking on a letter, then a refiner, the letter is no longer selected.  When I click all on the refiner, the letter is highlighted again.  I'm not great with editing the display templates so I'm hoping someone could help point out the issue.

Thanks so much in advance.